# Extbase stores empty values in database

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am trying to create an object, but the values are not stored into the database. This is done on an "index"-action because the plugin is inserted via TypoScript and actually does not create output. So there is no object given when calling the action, that's why I am creating it by myself.

```
$stat = new Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Stat;
$stat->setSubscriberId($_COOKIE['statid']);
$stat->setDomain($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$stat->setRequestUri($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$this->statRepository = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_myExt_Domain_Repository_StatRepository');
$this->statRepository->add($stat);
```

doing a `var_dump($stat)` gives the following:

```
object(Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Stat)#191 (9) {
  ["subscriber_id":protected]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["domain":protected]=>
  string(22) "test.localhost.example"
  ["request_uri":protected]=>
  string(26) "/testpage/index.php?id=2"
  ["uid":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_localizedUid":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_languageUid":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["pid":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_isClone":"Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractDomainObject":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_cleanProperties":"Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractDomainObject":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

So this looks like the values are assigned properly. But when looking into the database, I get this:

```
uid    pid    subscriber_id    domain    request_uri    crdate  
13     0      0                NULL      NULL           1328176026
```

Repository:

```
class Tx_MyExt_Domain_Repository_StatRepository extends Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Repository
{}
```

Model:

```
class Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Stat extends Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity 
{

    /**
     * @var int
     * @dontvalidate
     */
    protected $subscriber_id = 0;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @dontvalidate
     */
    protected $domain = '';

    /**
     * @var string
     * @dontvalidate
     */
    protected $request_uri = '';



    /**
     * @param int $susbcriber_id Subscriber id
     * @return void
     */
    public function setSubscriberId($subscriber_id) 
    {
        $this->subscriber_id = $subscriber_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int Susbcriber id
     */
    public function getSubscriberId() 
    {
        return $this->subscriber_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $domain Domain
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDomain($domain)
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }

    /**
     * @return string Domain
     */
    public function getDomain() 
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $request_uri Request URI
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRequestUri($request_uri)
    {
        $this->request_uri = $request_uri;
    }

    /**
     * @return string Request URI
     */
    public function getRequestUri() 
    {
        return $this->request_uri;
    }

}
```

Can someone give me advise what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debugged through the whole extbase process. It seems that in `typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Backend.php`, the attributes are skipped on this line:

```
if (!$dataMap->isPersistableProperty($propertyName) || $this->propertyValueIsLazyLoaded($propertyValue)) continue;
```

This because `$dataMap->isPersistableProperty($propertyName)` doesn't return something. Investigating in `typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Mapper`, there is:

```
/**
 * Returns TRUE if the property is persistable (configured in $TCA)
 *
 * @param string $propertyName The property name
 * @return boolean TRUE if the property is persistable (configured in $TCA)
 */
public function isPersistableProperty($propertyName) {
    return isset($this->columnMaps[$propertyName]);
}
```

So the solution is quite simple: create a valid TCA. I didn't had one (or a too minimalistic)  since the table i am using is not going to be displayed in the backend.

Answer (score 3):

While misconfiguration of TCA might be causing the problem, there might be others. For example, extbase does not like it when you are defining unique keys and fails silently.

Having struggeld with the problems in multiple projects, I am now using the following debugging routine for projects made with the extension builder

- Remove your own additions from the table related classes and as well from typoscript. This has to be done for ext_tables.php, ext_tables.sql, all files in Configuration/TCA and Configuration/Typoscript if you have changed their state in *Configuration/ExtensionBuilder/settings.yaml* to merge or keep.
- Check if your application now does save. If not, report a detailed bug report to exentension builder.
- Normally your application should save now. Readd recursively the changes you've made until you find the error. Start with ext_tables.sql (don't forget you have to remove and readd the database every time), go on with ext_tables.php, Configuration/TCA/* and end with Configuration/Typoscript (it's my personal experience that these order is the fastest)
- Report your stuff to the extbase team and add it to this thread (as it's the  first google hit when you experience the error)